# How did words starting with f- become h-?

Tags: etimología, latín, consonantes

Many Spanish words that nowadays begin with h- used to begin with f-, for example:

- *hacer* < *facere* (PT *fazer*, IT *fare*, FR *faire*),
- *hijo* < *filius* (PT *filho*, IT *figlio*, FR *fils*)
- *haya* < *fagea* (PT *faia*)

Can anyone explain this change?

Comment: This is a very complex question, you have a whole [article in the Spanish Wikipedia](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cambio_fonético_«f_→_h»_del_español).

Comment: @Charlie Thanks, but I don't read intensive Spanish and that page doesn't have an English version so I missed it.

Comment: The first tobacco growing and processing in Spain happens in XVI century in Sevilla. This is interesting to know since in Spanish the word for smoke is `humo` with **h** while smoking is `fumar` with **f**. Probably the bad habit of smoking came to Spain after the process of changing f for h ended. Maybe in it's time `fumar` was a loanword that came to Spanish with it's original **f**

Comment: I didn't actually do the right thing and check if there was an answer already, but I don't think the answer I gave is a duplicate. (That one was a "why" answer pointing to substrate influence; mine is more of a "how" answer with more general "why" bullet points.) The question itself *is* a duplicate, though. What should we do? I can move my answer to the other question, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How it *exactly* happened is unknown. The change itself is not really difficult to imagine. It's a frequent phonetic change in many languages.* One can say it's a kind of **lenition** (weakening): /f/ involves a well-marked friction between the lips and the teeth, while /h/ is considered by some to be less than a full fricative consonant (more like an approximant).

Why was /f/ prone to change?

1. Vulgar Latin /f/ was probably not actually labiodental but [bilabial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiceless_bilabial_fricative) [ɸ] (like blowing air out through almost closed lips), so it was rather weak to begin with.
2. This /f/ was the only fricative in that point of articulation, and the only fricative in the whole system other than /s/, which was much more common; it was phonologically isolated, the odd one out. Such isolation tends to favor the change or disappearance of sounds. On the other hand this also meant that /f/ could sound really like our labiodental [f] or else like bilabial [ɸ], as [that would make no difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_variation).
3. Latin /f/ was also very restricted in its position: for historical reasons it only appeared at the beginning of native Latin roots. (It could appear elsewhere in words like *dēfendere*, derived from a root *fend-*, or in borrowings like *rūfus*.)

All of these made it easy for /f/ to change its pronunciation. In some regions it seems that /f/ was pronounced [h] before posterior vowels (/o/ and /u/) and [ɸ] before the other vowels and consonants like /r/ and /l/. In some others, particularly in northern Castile (where modern standard Spanish comes from), it apparently changed to [h] everywhere. There are traces of this change already in the 9th century. Even then this [h] was disappearing, continuing a process that had already begun in Vulgar Latin.

The only place where /f/ (pronounced [hɸ]) was kept was before [w], that is, in words like *fuego* (< Latin *focum*). This would later revert to [f], as well as other words, generally borrowed from Latin or other languages as learned terms (*cultismos*).

---

*For a quick reference, check out [Index Diachronica](https://chridd.nfshost.com/diachronica/search?q=f#from); this shows a list of documented instances of /f/ becoming something else in lots of languages (search the page for things like **f → h** and **f → ɸ**).